# Javascript integration with django template problem

Tags: django, django-templates

In my django project when i write show password script within login.html file it works fine but when i place the script in static directory of my project it will effect email and password1 field not password1 and password2 field.

```
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load socialaccount %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Notes/signup.css' %}" />
    <!--Font Awesome Link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    <title>Signup Page</title>
</head>
<style>
  .errors label{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 9px;
  }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="login" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
            <h1>Signup</h1>
            {% render_field form.username type="text" placeholder="Username" %}
            {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == "username error" %}
            <div class="errors">
            <label><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i>{{message}}</label>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% render_field form.email type="email" placeholder="Email" %}
            {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == "email error" %}
            <div class="errors">
            <label><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i>{{message}}</label>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% render_field form.password1 type="password" placeholder="Password" %}
            {% render_field form.password2 type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" %}
            {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == "password2 error" %}
            <div class="errors">
            <label><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i>{{message}}</label>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <input type="checkbox" id="show" /><label>Show Password</label>
            <button class="btn" style="margin-top: 20px">Signup</button>
            <div class="signup-location">
                <h2>
                    Already have an Account?
                    <a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="or"><span></span>or<span></span></div>
            <br /><br />
          <button class="btn facebook"><a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook" style="margin-left: 15px"></i> Signup
          with Facebook
          </a></button>
        <button class="btn google"><a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus-g" style="margin-left: 10px"></i>
          Signup with Google
        <a/></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const checkBox = document.getElementById("show");
    const passwordInput1 = document.getElementById("id_password1");
    const passwordInput2 = document.getElementById("id_password2");
  
    checkBox.addEventListener("change", function () {
      const inputType = checkBox.checked ? "text" : "password";
      passwordInput1.type = inputType;
      passwordInput2.type = inputType;
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

This is my html file and script is included in it.But when i remove this and add its path as  it will not work fine.
I have tried all the alternatives from gpt.